# Remote debugging in Windows Embedded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, windows-embedded

I'm moving from Windows CE 6 to Windows Embedded Standard 7 for a project and am wondering how remote debugging of .Net apps works with Windows Embedded target devices.  In CE with VS2008 and ActiveSync (USB), I can hit F5 and my app is automatically deployed to the target device and executed so I can step through my breakpoints just like I would if I were debugging locally.

Is there an equivalent remote debugging solution for Windows Embedded debugging?  A quick glance through the Visual Studio "Remote Debugger" documentation makes the whole thing seem a lot clunkier/less integrated.  Is there an easy way to debug applications on target devices running Windows Embedded like I would with CE?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience doing this over standard network interfaces on a Embedded Std7, but I guess the approach using an ActiveSync connection is exactly the same (as ActiveSync devices like my cellphone turn up under 'My Computer'); in short:

- suppose the Embedded device is on \\Embedded
- share a directory on the Embedded device, say 'temp'
- start the remote debugger client on your device
- point the output directory of your VS project to \\Embedded\temp
- set the options for your project to remote debugging on \\Embedded
- hitting F5 will build the exe, put it in \\Embedded\temp and start debugging it

Look [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/2/862977E5-8D21-4A1C-8DC9-C2289244C14C/Developing,%20Deploying,%20and%20Debugging%20Applications%20on%20Windows%20Embedded%20Standard%207.pdf) for the document that got me started.